# How to resolve SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2, virtualhost

I have setup a subdomain with ssl enabled on unbutu running apache.
But when I access the application on the domain the browser throws this error Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to xx.abd.com.
Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
Error code: SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT. Below is my vhost configurations.
Any help on how to resolve this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName xxx.xxxx.com
        ServerAlias www.xxx.abc.com
        Redirect permanent / https://xxx.abc.com/

        ServerAdmin info@healthneutron.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sitename/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        <Directory /var/www/html/sitename/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xxx.abc.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sitename/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/healthneutron_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/healthneutron_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/healthneutron_com.ca-bundle

    <Directory /var/www/html/sitename/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```